# Stripe API Error "Must supply either a card, customer, or bank account to create a token."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have been working on integrating Stripe with my application. Currently building a two sided marketplace.

Keep getting the error listed above even though I am using the card details they provide in the documentation/testing section.

Have tried a few fixes but can't seem to rectify the issue.

All the relevant code is attached below and would really appreciate a bit of help.

My **orders.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
 Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
 payment.setupForm()

payment =
 setupForm: ->
   $('#new_order').submit ->
    $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
    Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
    false

handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
if status == 200
  $('#new_order').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(response.id))
  $('#new_order')[0].submit()
else
  $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show()
  $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

my **_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="thumbnail">
  <%= image_tag @listing.image.url %>
</div>
 <h3><%= @listing.name %></h3>
 <h4><%= number_to_currency(@listing.price) %></h4>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
   <%= form_for([@listing, @order]) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times; </button>
      <h4><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h4>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div id="stripe_error" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none">
    <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :email %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :name %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :address %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :address, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :city %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :county %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :county, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :post_code %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :post_code, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :phone %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
     <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "number", class: "form-control" } %>
    <br>
    <%= label_tag :card_code, "CVC" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "cvc", class: "form-control" } %>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag nil, "Expiration Date" %>
    <%= select_month nil, { use_two_digit_numbers: true }, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "exp-month", class: "form-control" } %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= select_year nil, { start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+10 }, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "exp-year", class: "form-control" } %>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.submit "Complete Order", class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and finally my **orders_controller.rb**

```
  class OrdersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    # GET /orders
    # GET /orders.json

  def sales
   @orders = Order.all.where(seller: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def purchases
   @orders = Order.all.where(buyer: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
   end

   # GET /orders/new
   def new
    @order = Order.new
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    end

 # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
   def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    @seller = @listing.user

    @order.listing_id = @listing.id
    @order.buyer_id = current_user.id
    @order.seller_id = @seller.id

   Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
   token = params[:stripeToken]

  begin
   charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
    :currency => "gbp",
    :card => token
    )
   flash[:notice] = "Thanks for ordering!"
   rescue Stripe::CardError => e
   flash[:danger] = e.message
  end

   respond_to do |format|
   if @order.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
   else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
 end

# PATCH/PUT /orders/1
# PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json

 private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_order
   @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

   # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
     params.require(:order).permit(:email, :name, :address, :city, :county, :post_code, :phone)
 end
  end
```

Comment: Does what's posted here match what's in your code? If so, remember that CoffeeScript uses significant whitespace. As you've posted it, there is no `payment.handleStripeResponse` function for Stripe.js to callback (and thus no `stripeToken` param in your form).

Comment: Where is your `#new_order` form declared?

Comment: @Dhaulagiri In the form partial. `form_for` generates the id based on the controller action. OrdersController#new will build the form with an id of `new_order`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments above. I misdiagnosed the error and it was actually due to not receiving a token back. Once I knew this I was able to then track down the error.

Comment: If you could share how you fixed the error, it would be helpful as i am facing the same issue now.

Comment: Hi @Alfie. Unfortunately I can't recall what the fix was now. Going forward I will always post my solutions. Hope you have managed to find a fix.